# How to ignore Make output at quickfix in vim?

Tags: vim, gcc, makefile

What is the desired behaviour of vim's quickfix feature?
Should the quickfix window (:copen) only contain compiler errors/warnings or should the whole output be displayed?
I want the former, since the output of make can be very long, but I get the latter, even with compiler set to gcc and g:compiler_gcc_ignore_unmatched_lines set.
However, lines inside the quickfix window with warnings/errors are highlighted and :cnext correctly jumps to the next issue.
Furthermore, Lines without issues have a double pipe symbol prefixed, so it seems that vim properly parses the make output.

Are these lines displayed in addition to the warnings/errors and can be hidden or does the errorformat string not exactly match the make output?

I used the avrdude 5.11.1 sources as an example, but I get the same result with many other projects.

Does setting the compiler automatically adapt the errorformat string or do I have to set that string always manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's really however you want it to work. I often filter out some of the build output that I'm not interested in by adding grep to my makeprg, but I also want some of the build output even if it's not an error.

I don't think vim will remove non-error lines from the quickfix. If you don't want them there, you need to filter them yourself (or modify `efm` to include them in an error).